# Can purescript's type system solve nubbed rows

Tags: purescript

Suppose I have `type Open o = ( i :: Int | o )` and `type Closed = ( i :: Int )`. Then if I try to instantiate something like `{ i: 1 } :: Record (Open Closed)` I get an error because it's missing label `i`. So what I'd like to say is `{ i: 1 } :: forall n. Nub (Open Closed) n => n`.

That doesn't work though, and the error doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It says it can't match `t0` with `( i :: Int | t1 )` (t0 is bound, t1 is unknown) while checking that `{ i: 1 }` has type `Record t0`. And if I had an open row here I think I'd get it. If the type is open, the nub can't be uniquely determined. But as far as I can tell since it's trying to match `{ i: 1 }` with `Record t0` it should be trying to match `t0` with `( i :: Int )`, not `( i :: Int | t1 )`.

I thought that since there's a functional dependency on the `Nub` typeclass, and `Open Closed` is fully defined, `n` should be solvable. So I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve but you can just "close" your `Open` row type by passing empty row type to it `()` like: `{ i: 1 } :: Record (Open ())`.

Comment: Or using [`+`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-typelevel-prelude/5.0.2/docs/Type.Row#t:type%20(+)) from `typelevel-prelude` and record syntax: `{ i: 1 } :: { | Open + () }`

Comment: Sorry for the above spam - I should probably reread your question before throwing some comments.

Please notice that this `{ i: 1 } ∷ ∀ x. { | x }` raises the same exact error. I think that it is related to this issue: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/3242 . Please check Liam response there: "...solving constraints doesn't introduce axioms...". I hope you forgive me my lack of precision - I'm not a "compiler guy" and I should probably not comment under this question at all ;-)

Comment: the link is the answer I was looking for, so thanks. (If you post that with a sentence or two to the effect that typeclass constraints don't pass other information along to the function body, I'll mark it as accepted) One clarification though. We should expect `{ i: 1 } ∷ ∀ x. { | x }` to get that error, right? Since there's no guarantee `x` will have an `i :: Int` label, as opposed to the example in the question, where the constraint *does* imply the label, but it's not telling the values about it.

Comment: I think I'm going to cross post this question (if you don't mind) and my sketch response to our discourse community forum and get some more feedback. Then possibly I can turn my comment into a more useful and informative response. Is this plan ok for you?

Comment: no objections from me.